# I can not update or delete property. Get and Post methods work fine. I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf, delete-method

I see there are many questions for this question but nothing is helping.
I can't find the solution.
I can't set up the button links correctly.

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteProperty/{idProperty}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteProperty1(@PathVariable("idProperty") int idProperty) {
        propertyService.deleteById(idProperty);
        return "redirect:/admin/properties/allProperties";
    }
```

Update button:

```
@{/admin/properties/deleteProperty(idProperty=${tempProperty.idProperty})}"
```

Delete button:

```
@{/admin/properties/deleteProperty/{idProperty}'(idProperty=${tempProperty.idProperty})}"
```

Comment: `@{/admin/properties/deleteProperty{idProperty}'(idProperty=${tempProperty.idProperty})}"` there should not be apostrophe(') after `{idProperty}`. Try this `"@{/admin/properties/deleteProperty/{idProperty}(idProperty)=${tempProperty.idProperty}"`

Comment: @dhakalkumar I got this error
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "@{/admin/properties/deleteProperty{idProperty}(idProperty)=${tempProperty.idProperty})}"

Comment: If that is the exact error message you get, looks like you missed a / between `deleteProperty` and `{idProperty}` --> `@{/admin/properties/deleteProperty/{idProperty}(idProperty)...`

Comment: I have tried that too. When I added that slash you mentioned I got the Whitelabel error page...

Comment: In the controller methods, you can add a line `System.out.println(method-name)` to see which method is being called when you click on the buttons. If nothing is printed in the console, your code is not reaching the controller.

Comment: Browsers can normally only do GET and POST requests (unless you are using JavaScript to send an AJAX request).  How are you getting the browser to submit a DELETE request? Is it just a `<form method="DELETE" ... >` because that won't work.